# Is it possible to initiate a IP to IP connection between two ethernet ports of a PMC (PCI Mezzanine Card) card?

Tags: networking, routing, real-time

Is it possible to initiate a IP to IP connection between two ethernet ports of a PMC (PCI Mezzanine Card) card?

A physical network is divided into two subnets having 2 host each. These two ports are the members of two subnets respectively. For built in test I shall send a message from one ethernet port of a subnet to another port of the other subnet. I need to make this possible via an external cable.

As the message transfer is happening over the same device, will the driver allow the message to be sent from one port and taken out of the other port?

Comment: What's the make and model of the card?  They very likely can't see each other's traffic, but it may be that they support other modes where it is possible.

Comment: I'm thinking it's not possible, unless perhaps with two virtual systems that each had their own routing/device tables.

The problem being that a packet sent to a local address normally doesn't get routed, as it's already at its destination.